# sequel (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sequel

I am attempting to run a file that has the line `requires 'sequel'` on line 11. When I run the file, I get this error:

`/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sequel (LoadError)`

`from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'`

`from lib/pass_server_ctl:11`

I have installed the sequel ruby gem, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there was a configuration error in my environment settings. I also had to reinstall sequel and json. Problem solved after that!